# How to use array of values in angucomplete-alt as local-data?

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, autocomplete

I have an array in my controller which has only values and not objects. How can I use this array as local-data in angucomplete-alt. I am confused because i don't have key-value pairs because of which I can't define title-field and search-field!! Any help could be appreciated, Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you found any solution to this? Even I am facing the same issue. If you have used any other library then please suggest. I am using angular1.5.8

Comment: I had actually converted the array into an object and used it

Answer (score 2):

### (Off-topic) History

A few days ago I was also battling with auto-complete in AngularJS and I made a search for libraries.

Of all the possibilities offered, I decided to go with [Angular Material Auto-complete](https://material.angularjs.org/latest/demo/autocomplete).

The examples are interesting, and the basic one works, but unfortunately, since the other ones don't work (in codepen) and it no longer has support (as well as the rest of AngularJS) I decided to go ahead a create a github repo with my own examples you can see:

- https://github.com/Fl4m3Ph03n1x/material-complete
- https://github.com/Fl4m3Ph03n1x/custom-complete

It is important to notice that I am also battling with my own issues with Angular Material, and that is why I met you in AngularJS chat room and saw your question (quite funny, don't you think?), but I still believe this is an option to consider.

### Autocomplte-alt Documentation

The examples in the website may shed some light on your problem:

```
<div angucomplete-alt id="ex1"
  placeholder="Search countries"
  maxlength="50"
  pause="100"
  selected-object="selectedCountry"
  local-data="countries"
  search-fields="name"
  title-field="name"
  minlength="1"
  input-class="form-control form-control-small"
  match-class="highlight"></div>
```

### Answer

However, the documentation is brutally lacking. It shows no JS, something crucial, and no CSS. This is one of the reasons I decided to not pick that tool.

This aside, after reverse-engineering the website, I was able to find the JavaScript behind it. Following is the JavaScript code for all the examples:

```
var app = angular.module('app', ["ngTouch", "angucomplete-alt"]);

app.controller('MainController', ['$scope', '$http', '$rootScope',
  function MainController($scope, $http, $rootScope) {
    $scope.remoteUrlRequestFn = function(str) {
      return {q: str};
    };

    $scope.countrySelected = function(selected) {
      if (selected) {
        window.alert('You have selected ' + selected.title);
      } else {
        console.log('cleared');
      }
    };

    $scope.localSearch = function(str, people) {
      var matches = [];
      people.forEach(function(person) {
        var fullName = person.firstName + ' ' + person.surname;
        if ((person.firstName.toLowerCase().indexOf(str.toString().toLowerCase()) >= 0) ||
            (person.surname.toLowerCase().indexOf(str.toString().toLowerCase()) >= 0) ||
            (fullName.toLowerCase().indexOf(str.toString().toLowerCase()) >= 0)) {
          matches.push(person);
        }
      });
      return matches;
    };

    $scope.people = [
      {firstName: "Daryl", surname: "Rowland", twitter: "@darylrowland", pic: "img/daryl.jpeg"},
      {firstName: "Alan", surname: "Partridge", twitter: "@alangpartridge", pic: "img/alanp.jpg"},
      {firstName: "Annie", surname: "Rowland", twitter: "@anklesannie", pic: "img/annie.jpg"}
    ];

    $scope.countries = [
      {name: 'Afghanistan', code: 'AF'},
      {name: 'Aland Islands', code: 'AX'},
      {name: 'Albania', code: 'AL'},
      {name: 'Algeria', code: 'DZ'},
      {name: 'American Samoa', code: 'AS'},
      {name: 'AndorrA', code: 'AD'},
      {name: 'Angola', code: 'AO'},
      {name: 'Anguilla', code: 'AI'},
      {name: 'Antarctica', code: 'AQ'},
      {name: 'Antigua and Barbuda', code: 'AG'},
      {name: 'Argentina', code: 'AR'},
      {name: 'Armenia', code: 'AM'},
      {name: 'Aruba', code: 'AW'},
      {name: 'Australia', code: 'AU'},
      {name: 'Austria', code: 'AT'},
      {name: 'Azerbaijan', code: 'AZ'},
      {name: 'Bahamas', code: 'BS'},
      {name: 'Bahrain', code: 'BH'},
      {name: 'Bangladesh', code: 'BD'},
      {name: 'Barbados', code: 'BB'},
      {name: 'Belarus', code: 'BY'},
      {name: 'Belgium', code: 'BE'},
      {name: 'Belize', code: 'BZ'},
      {name: 'Benin', code: 'BJ'},
      {name: 'Bermuda', code: 'BM'},
      {name: 'Bhutan', code: 'BT'},
      {name: 'Bolivia', code: 'BO'},
      {name: 'Bosnia and Herzegovina', code: 'BA'},
      {name: 'Botswana', code: 'BW'},
      {name: 'Bouvet Island', code: 'BV'},
      {name: 'Brazil', code: 'BR'},
      {name: 'British Indian Ocean Territory', code: 'IO'},
      {name: 'Brunei Darussalam', code: 'BN'},
      {name: 'Bulgaria', code: 'BG'},
      {name: 'Burkina Faso', code: 'BF'},
      {name: 'Burundi', code: 'BI'},
      {name: 'Cambodia', code: 'KH'},
      {name: 'Cameroon', code: 'CM'},
      {name: 'Canada', code: 'CA'},
      {name: 'Cape Verde', code: 'CV'},
      {name: 'Cayman Islands', code: 'KY'},
      {name: 'Central African Republic', code: 'CF'},
      {name: 'Chad', code: 'TD'},
      {name: 'Chile', code: 'CL'},
      {name: 'China', code: 'CN'},
      {name: 'Christmas Island', code: 'CX'},
      {name: 'Cocos (Keeling) Islands', code: 'CC'},
      {name: 'Colombia', code: 'CO'},
      {name: 'Comoros', code: 'KM'},
      {name: 'Congo', code: 'CG'},
      {name: 'Congo, The Democratic Republic of the', code: 'CD'},
      {name: 'Cook Islands', code: 'CK'},
      {name: 'Costa Rica', code: 'CR'},
      {name: 'Cote D\'Ivoire', code: 'CI'},
      {name: 'Croatia', code: 'HR'},
      {name: 'Cuba', code: 'CU'},
      {name: 'Cyprus', code: 'CY'},
      {name: 'Czech Republic', code: 'CZ'},
      {name: 'Denmark', code: 'DK'},
      {name: 'Djibouti', code: 'DJ'},
      {name: 'Dominica', code: 'DM'},
      {name: 'Dominican Republic', code: 'DO'},
      {name: 'Ecuador', code: 'EC'},
      {name: 'Egypt', code: 'EG'},
      {name: 'El Salvador', code: 'SV'},
      {name: 'Equatorial Guinea', code: 'GQ'},
      {name: 'Eritrea', code: 'ER'},
      {name: 'Estonia', code: 'EE'},
      {name: 'Ethiopia', code: 'ET'},
      {name: 'Falkland Islands (Malvinas)', code: 'FK'},
      {name: 'Faroe Islands', code: 'FO'},
      {name: 'Fiji', code: 'FJ'},
      {name: 'Finland', code: 'FI'},
      {name: 'France', code: 'FR'},
      {name: 'French Guiana', code: 'GF'},
      {name: 'French Polynesia', code: 'PF'},
      {name: 'French Southern Territories', code: 'TF'},
      {name: 'Gabon', code: 'GA'},
      {name: 'Gambia', code: 'GM'},
      {name: 'Georgia', code: 'GE'},
      {name: 'Germany', code: 'DE'},
      {name: 'Ghana', code: 'GH'},
      {name: 'Gibraltar', code: 'GI'},
      {name: 'Greece', code: 'GR'},
      {name: 'Greenland', code: 'GL'},
      {name: 'Grenada', code: 'GD'},
      {name: 'Guadeloupe', code: 'GP'},
      {name: 'Guam', code: 'GU'},
      {name: 'Guatemala', code: 'GT'},
      {name: 'Guernsey', code: 'GG'},
      {name: 'Guinea', code: 'GN'},
      {name: 'Guinea-Bissau', code: 'GW'},
      {name: 'Guyana', code: 'GY'},
      {name: 'Haiti', code: 'HT'},
      {name: 'Heard Island and Mcdonald Islands', code: 'HM'},
      {name: 'Holy See (Vatican City State)', code: 'VA'},
      {name: 'Honduras', code: 'HN'},
      {name: 'Hong Kong', code: 'HK'},
      {name: 'Hungary', code: 'HU'},
      {name: 'Iceland', code: 'IS'},
      {name: 'India', code: 'IN'},
      {name: 'Indonesia', code: 'ID'},
      {name: 'Iran, Islamic Republic Of', code: 'IR'},
      {name: 'Iraq', code: 'IQ'},
      {name: 'Ireland', code: 'IE'},
      {name: 'Isle of Man', code: 'IM'},
      {name: 'Israel', code: 'IL'},
      {name: 'Italy', code: 'IT'},
      {name: 'Jamaica', code: 'JM'},
      {name: 'Japan', code: 'JP'},
      {name: 'Jersey', code: 'JE'},
      {name: 'Jordan', code: 'JO'},
      {name: 'Kazakhstan', code: 'KZ'},
      {name: 'Kenya', code: 'KE'},
      {name: 'Kiribati', code: 'KI'},
      {name: 'Korea, Democratic People\'S Republic of', code: 'KP'},
      {name: 'Korea, Republic of', code: 'KR'},
      {name: 'Kuwait', code: 'KW'},
      {name: 'Kyrgyzstan', code: 'KG'},
      {name: 'Lao People\'S Democratic Republic', code: 'LA'},
      {name: 'Latvia', code: 'LV'},
      {name: 'Lebanon', code: 'LB'},
      {name: 'Lesotho', code: 'LS'},
      {name: 'Liberia', code: 'LR'},
      {name: 'Libyan Arab Jamahiriya', code: 'LY'},
      {name: 'Liechtenstein', code: 'LI'},
      {name: 'Lithuania', code: 'LT'},
      {name: 'Luxembourg', code: 'LU'},
      {name: 'Macao', code: 'MO'},
      {name: 'Macedonia, The Former Yugoslav Republic of', code: 'MK'},
      {name: 'Madagascar', code: 'MG'},
      {name: 'Malawi', code: 'MW'},
      {name: 'Malaysia', code: 'MY'},
      {name: 'Maldives', code: 'MV'},
      {name: 'Mali', code: 'ML'},
      {name: 'Malta', code: 'MT'},
      {name: 'Marshall Islands', code: 'MH'},
      {name: 'Martinique', code: 'MQ'},
      {name: 'Mauritania', code: 'MR'},
      {name: 'Mauritius', code: 'MU'},
      {name: 'Mayotte', code: 'YT'},
      {name: 'Mexico', code: 'MX'},
      {name: 'Micronesia, Federated States of', code: 'FM'},
      {name: 'Moldova, Republic of', code: 'MD'},
      {name: 'Monaco', code: 'MC'},
      {name: 'Mongolia', code: 'MN'},
      {name: 'Montserrat', code: 'MS'},
      {name: 'Morocco', code: 'MA'},
      {name: 'Mozambique', code: 'MZ'},
      {name: 'Myanmar', code: 'MM'},
      {name: 'Namibia', code: 'NA'},
      {name: 'Nauru', code: 'NR'},
      {name: 'Nepal', code: 'NP'},
      {name: 'Netherlands', code: 'NL'},
      {name: 'Netherlands Antilles', code: 'AN'},
      {name: 'New Caledonia', code: 'NC'},
      {name: 'New Zealand', code: 'NZ'},
      {name: 'Nicaragua', code: 'NI'},
      {name: 'Niger', code: 'NE'},
      {name: 'Nigeria', code: 'NG'},
      {name: 'Niue', code: 'NU'},
      {name: 'Norfolk Island', code: 'NF'},
      {name: 'Northern Mariana Islands', code: 'MP'},
      {name: 'Norway', code: 'NO'},
      {name: 'Oman', code: 'OM'},
      {name: 'Pakistan', code: 'PK'},
      {name: 'Palau', code: 'PW'},
      {name: 'Palestinian Territory, Occupied', code: 'PS'},
      {name: 'Panama', code: 'PA'},
      {name: 'Papua New Guinea', code: 'PG'},
      {name: 'Paraguay', code: 'PY'},
      {name: 'Peru', code: 'PE'},
      {name: 'Philippines', code: 'PH'},
      {name: 'Pitcairn', code: 'PN'},
      {name: 'Poland', code: 'PL'},
      {name: 'Portugal', code: 'PT'},
      {name: 'Puerto Rico', code: 'PR'},
      {name: 'Qatar', code: 'QA'},
      {name: 'Reunion', code: 'RE'},
      {name: 'Romania', code: 'RO'},
      {name: 'Russian Federation', code: 'RU'},
      {name: 'RWANDA', code: 'RW'},
      {name: 'Saint Helena', code: 'SH'},
      {name: 'Saint Kitts and Nevis', code: 'KN'},
      {name: 'Saint Lucia', code: 'LC'},
      {name: 'Saint Pierre and Miquelon', code: 'PM'},
      {name: 'Saint Vincent and the Grenadines', code: 'VC'},
      {name: 'Samoa', code: 'WS'},
      {name: 'San Marino', code: 'SM'},
      {name: 'Sao Tome and Principe', code: 'ST'},
      {name: 'Saudi Arabia', code: 'SA'},
      {name: 'Senegal', code: 'SN'},
      {name: 'Serbia and Montenegro', code: 'CS'},
      {name: 'Seychelles', code: 'SC'},
      {name: 'Sierra Leone', code: 'SL'},
      {name: 'Singapore', code: 'SG'},
      {name: 'Slovakia', code: 'SK'},
      {name: 'Slovenia', code: 'SI'},
      {name: 'Solomon Islands', code: 'SB'},
      {name: 'Somalia', code: 'SO'},
      {name: 'South Africa', code: 'ZA'},
      {name: 'South Georgia and the South Sandwich Islands', code: 'GS'},
      {name: 'Spain', code: 'ES'},
      {name: 'Sri Lanka', code: 'LK'},
      {name: 'Sudan', code: 'SD'},
      {name: 'Suriname', code: 'SR'},
      {name: 'Svalbard and Jan Mayen', code: 'SJ'},
      {name: 'Swaziland', code: 'SZ'},
      {name: 'Sweden', code: 'SE'},
      {name: 'Switzerland', code: 'CH'},
      {name: 'Syrian Arab Republic', code: 'SY'},
      {name: 'Taiwan, Province of China', code: 'TW'},
      {name: 'Tajikistan', code: 'TJ'},
      {name: 'Tanzania, United Republic of', code: 'TZ'},
      {name: 'Thailand', code: 'TH'},
      {name: 'Timor-Leste', code: 'TL'},
      {name: 'Togo', code: 'TG'},
      {name: 'Tokelau', code: 'TK'},
      {name: 'Tonga', code: 'TO'},
      {name: 'Trinidad and Tobago', code: 'TT'},
      {name: 'Tunisia', code: 'TN'},
      {name: 'Turkey', code: 'TR'},
      {name: 'Turkmenistan', code: 'TM'},
      {name: 'Turks and Caicos Islands', code: 'TC'},
      {name: 'Tuvalu', code: 'TV'},
      {name: 'Uganda', code: 'UG'},
      {name: 'Ukraine', code: 'UA'},
      {name: 'United Arab Emirates', code: 'AE'},
      {name: 'United Kingdom', code: 'GB'},
      {name: 'United States', code: 'US'},
      {name: 'United States Minor Outlying Islands', code: 'UM'},
      {name: 'Uruguay', code: 'UY'},
      {name: 'Uzbekistan', code: 'UZ'},
      {name: 'Vanuatu', code: 'VU'},
      {name: 'Venezuela', code: 'VE'},
      {name: 'Vietnam', code: 'VN'},
      {name: 'Virgin Islands, British', code: 'VG'},
      {name: 'Virgin Islands, U.S.', code: 'VI'},
      {name: 'Wallis and Futuna', code: 'WF'},
      {name: 'Western Sahara', code: 'EH'},
      {name: 'Yemen', code: 'YE'},
      {name: 'Zambia', code: 'ZM'},
      {name: 'Zimbabwe', code: 'ZW'}
    ];

    $scope.countrySelected9 = {name: 'Zimbabwe', code: 'ZW'};
    $scope.countrySelectedFn9 = function(selected) {
      if (selected) {
        $scope.countrySelected9 = selected.originalObject;
      } else {
        $scope.countrySelected9 = null;
      }
    }

    $scope.selectedCountry16 = {name: 'Russia'};

    $scope.inputChanged = function(str) {
      $scope.console10 = str;
    }

    $scope.focusState = 'None';
    $scope.focusIn = function() {
      var focusInputElem = document.getElementById('ex12_value');
      $scope.focusState = 'In';
      focusInputElem.classList.remove('small-input');
    }
    $scope.focusOut = function() {
      var focusInputElem = document.getElementById('ex12_value');
      $scope.focusState = 'Out';
      focusInputElem.classList.add('small-input');
    }

    /***
     * Send a broadcast to the directive in order to clear itself
     * if an id parameter is given only this ancucomplete is cleared
     * @param id
     */
    $scope.clearInput = function (id) {
      if (id) {
        $scope.$broadcast('angucomplete-alt:clearInput', id);
      }
      else{
        $scope.$broadcast('angucomplete-alt:clearInput');
      }
    }

    /***
     * Send a broadcast to the directive in order to change itself
     * if an id parameter is given only this ancucomplete is changed
     * @param id
     */
    $scope.changeInput = function (id) {
      if (id) {
        var pos = Math.floor(Math.random() * ($scope.countries.length - 1));
        $scope.$broadcast('angucomplete-alt:changeInput', id, $scope.countries[pos]);
      }
    }

    $scope.disableInput = true;

    $scope.requireExample8a = true;
    $scope.requireExample8b = true;
  }
]);
```

I believe this is what you need, this code should show you how you can set your controller, and it also has the **huge** list of countries inside it as well, so you can also use it.

Admittedly, I should not have to do this in order to access the documentation of a working example, but I found no other way of doing it.

I hope it helps !